# Comparing bond lengths of a molecule using valence bond theory?

Tags: valence-bond-theory

My textbook says that all the bonds of $\ce{SF4} $ are not equal while in the case of $\ce{XeF_2}$, $ \ce{BF4-} $ or $\ce{SiF4} $ all the bonds are equal. No reason is stated for this observation.

So is there a general way or formula to check if all the bond lengths are equal or not for a given molecule?

Comment: Please use the `mhchem` package for $\LaTeX$ formatting. Chemical formulas and equations mustn't be slanted.

Comment: You have to check geometry of the molecule

Comment: So the geometry will be trigonal bypyramidal, trigonal bypyramidal, square planar and square planar for $\ce{SF4} $, $\ce{XeF_2}$, $ \ce{BF4-} $ and $\ce{SiF4} $, respectively. What should I do next?

Comment: Where in this question comes the valence bond theory into play? Currently it reads more like a question about the simple predictions of the VSEPR model, geometries of certain molecules. It does not seem to be at all about VBT. Maybe some other tags and a more descriptive title would help this question.

Comment: 4 times wrong, sorry but without knowing VSEPR case is bad. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-f-replaces-axial-bond-in-pcl%e2%82%85 may help

Comment: Did you mean the the shape of the molecules or the geometry of the molecules?   The VSEPR of the molecules will be 5(4 bond pair, 1 lone pair), 6 (4 bond pair, 2 lone pair), 4(4 bond pair, 0 lone pair) and 4 ( 4 bond pair, 0 lone pair) for $\ce{SF4}$ , $\ce{XeF_2}$, $ \ce{BF4-} $ and $\ce{SiF4}$ ,respectively. I asked my teacher and he said that the molecule with VSEPR 3 or 5 has to be the answer. So the answer has to be $\ce{SF4} $