# In PCl2F3, why are two Cl atoms not on axial position?

Tags: molecular-structure, electronegativity, vsepr-theory

According to these sites:

1. [Chemistry Help](http://tutor-homework.com/Chemistry_Help/Molecular_Geometry/041_Phosphorus_Trifluoride_Dichloride_PF3Cl2.html)
2. [Molbase](http://www.molbase.com/en/13454-99-4-moldata-2555619.html)

in $\ce{PCl2F3}$, both $\ce{Cl}$ and one $\ce{F}$ atom are on equatorial position, and other 2 $\ce{F}$ atoms are on axial position as follows:

[image]

The first site mentions that to minimise repulsions of $\ce{F - F}$ bonds. But this structure is in fact increasing the repulsions, and decreasing stability, since the bond angle of $\ce{F - P - F}$ bond will be about $\mathrm{90^\circ}$

If instead all the $\ce{F}$ atoms are on equatorial position, and the 2 $\ce{Cl}$ on axial positions, then the repulsion may be further minimized.

So according to me, the structure should be:

[image]

**Question**: Why is my structure wrong? Please explain. Thank you!

Comment: See, the repulsion is not only between fluorines.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But $\rm F$ on equitorial position is a menace for all. It will repel the two $\rm F$ on axial very strongly, and also repel the chlorine.

Comment: True, but chlorine would repel chlorine even **stronger**.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thats why i placed the $\rm Cl$ atoms on axial position. This also gives symmetry to molecule. The site I linked said that Fluorine's bond $e^-$ repel more strongly due to its greater electronegativity

Comment: Molecules do not care about symmetry. As for the repulsion, well, looks like the site was wrong on this one.

Comment: Strongly related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-does-f-replace-the-axial-bond-in-pcl5/18544#18544

Comment: I am VTCing as a duplicate. The sole difference is the number of chlorines.