# where will be highly electronegetive atom placed?

Tags: vsepr-theory

consider a molecule PCl3F2 here F is more electronegetive than Cl, which of them should occupy axial position??when i searched on internet i found these two images , they increased my confusion instead of solving my problem.can anyone breifly explain me the which one would be on axial position(F or Cl).[image: f on axial bonds]
[image: one f on axial bond and one f on equitorial bond]

Comment: also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/45058/in-pcl2f3-why-are-two-cl-atoms-not-on-axial-position

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic50022a021?src=recsys