Hybridisation/bonding of XRn oxides
PH3 has a bond angle of around 93o, suggesting the s orbital has a minor role in the bonding, with the p orbitals in p-s σ bonding contributing to the orthogonality of the bonds according to Drago’s rule. Is hybridisation reintroduced in the case of PH3O with an sp3 lone pair forming a dative covalent bond to the O?
Likewise, in the case of (CH3)2S, the bond angle is 98.4o, again conforming to Drago’s. But what exactly happens in (CH3)2SO (DMSO) and (CH3)2SO2 (DMSO2)? What are the hybridisations (if any) in those?
First question on this forum, apologise for any syntactic errors.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/what-is-dragos-rule-does-it-really-exist

The act of hybridization is a concept used to ease understanding about how covalent bonds form - Phosphine is a chemical that is an example of disproving the theory. So you can't reintroduce hybridization. The bonding in phoshine oxide  also really  confuses the matter and phosphine oxide is a really unstable not talked about chemical

Hybridisation is not a necessary concept to be introduced in these molecules if you want to explain their geometry. It is sufficient to admit that lone pairs are more cumbersome than sigma bonds.
