# Geometries of SCl2(OCH3)2 and SF2(OCH3)2

Tags: molecular-structure, electronegativity, vsepr-theory

I am not able to understand the difference between structure of $\ce{SCl_{2}(OCH_{3})_{2}}$ and $\ce{SF_{2}(OCH_{3})_{2}}$.

I am already well versed with Molecular Orbital and VSEPR theories. I found the geometries,
but don't understand why they are:

[image]

Why is the $\ce{F}$ at axial positions and $\ce{Cl}$ on the other hand in equatorial positions? (I am not able to understand Bent's Rule to be straight-forward, I have read Wikipedia already.)

Comment: Related: [Why does F replace the axial bond in PCl5?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18427/16683)

Comment: As a general reminder: The involvement of d-orbitals into the bonding is one of the many shortcomings of VSEPR theory. The sp³d hybridisation simply is not evident (and it is not necessary) in the bonding of these molecules. I can't stress that enough. Textbooks which still rely on this explanation are outdated and desperately need revision.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now.....  Things became more clearer by Ron's answer to the question suggested above by Orthocresol (Thanks!) and I got to know that my textbook is outdated, cheers to Martin.

Comment: @orthocresol I'm not sure that Bent's rule is straight forward to use here, and I am especially not sure, whether the given geometries are indeed correct. From my initial calculations, the lowest energy structure also has a co-linear arrangement of Cl-S-Cl.

Answer (score -1):

Check the bond angles. The larger the angles around a bond, the more S character.
Electronegative elements prefer higher P character(Therefore less the bond angles).
Axial position has lesser bond angles.Hence higher electronegative element takes axial position.( F>O>Cl)

This concept however may not be applicable to every compound.