# Which substitutent should be placed on axial position in SCl2(OCH3)2?

Tags: molecular-structure, hybridization, electronegativity, inductive-effect

According to Bent's rule, in $\mathrm{sp^3d}$ more electronegative element is placed on the axial position, so between $\ce{Cl}$ and $\ce{OCH3}$ in $\ce{SCl2(OCH3)2}$ which should be placed on axial as oxygen is more electronegative, but wouldn't $\ce{CH3}$ reduce its overall electronegativity due to its positive inductive effect?The electronegativity of Oxygen is more than that of chlorine but **the negative inductive effect of OCH3 is less than that of Chlorine**

But my teacher said that $\ce{OCH3}$ should still be placed on axial position considering electronegativity of oxygen.

Can someone please explain this? Because we are comparing a group's electronegativity (which cannot be found on the Pauling scale) to that of an atom.

Comment: What can be done to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: Related: [Geometries of SCl2(OCH3)2 and SF2(OCH3)2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74359/geometries-of-scl2och32-and-sf2och32)

Comment: This post does not explain why OCH3 is placed at axial...I have seen this post before and found it to be giving a  conceptual understanding of Bent's rule at a basic level but my question is slightly different

Comment: EN of $\ce{O > Cl}$, but [_-I effect_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect) of $\ce{OCH_3^- < Cl^-}$. May I add this point in question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion have added that in question...am hoping for a proper answer to this now