# Bond orders in the 3c-4e bond and 3c-2e bond

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory

According to D. P. M. Mingos, in his book Essential Trends in Inorganic Chemistry, the bond order of the three-centre four-electron bond is approximately 0.717, which is one divided by the square root of 2. However, in the case of the three-centre two-electron bond, the bond order is 0.5. This would imply that the former is stronger than the latter. However, both of them have similar-looking molecular orbital diagrams. In the case of the former, the nonbonding MO is filled while in the case of the latter, only the bonding MO is filled. Thus, from the MO perspective, why would these two bonds have different bond orders?

Comment: Not sure about this one, but I suspect it depends on how one defines the bond order. See eg IUPAC Gold Book for a complicated definition. Does Mingos not give any kind of justification?

Comment: Mingos has indeed justified the bond order for the 3c-4e bond mathematically (by using the definition of bond order to be the product of the coefficients of the orbitals contributing to the bond times the number of electrons occupying the orbital). However, he did not justify the bond order of o.5 for the 3c-2e bond.

Comment: Oh, ok. I have a hunch I *might* be able to answer this one, but again, not right now... Good questions, though.

Comment: I would guess that at least in the simplest cases of three-center bonding, the bond order is the same with two or four electrons should be the same; the second electron pair is in an essentially nonbonding orbital.

Comment: Revisiting this I don't see how the maths works out. I have seen this definition before, but if I assume the usual form of the MOs for three-centre bonding, the population of the middle MO should not affect the bond order between adjacent atoms because the coefficient of the central atom is zero. Probably need more details from the book.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Doesn't bond order reduce when there is the filling of the nonbonding orbitals. Ron writes "Notice how the four electrons are distributed - there are two electrons in the HOMO which is a non-bonding MO, so the bond order in this bond is reduced." in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-does-f-replace-the-axial-bond-in-pcl5/18544?noredirect=1#comment154935_18544

Comment: What bonding is taken away by filling a _non_bonding orbital?

Comment: @orthocresol Unfortunately, there were not many other details from the book. This book isn't so much based on a mathematical understanding of bonding. So I can't help you with that...

Comment: @OscarLanzi I agree with you too. The book says that a 3c-4e bond and a 3c-2e bond have the same MO diagram, just that in the case of the former, the nonbonding MO is also filled. However, I was thinking shouldn't there be more fundamental differences between these two bonds. The 3c-4e bond is used to rationalise hypervalency while the 3c-2e bond is used to rationalise hypovalency. These are two very different uses.