# What studies show that d orbitals don't play an important role in covalent bonding? (> period 2 elements)

Tags: bond, theoretical-chemistry, reference-request, lewis-structure

Take a look at all the following molecules: $\ce{SO3^{2-}}$, $\ce{SO2}$, $\ce{SO4^2-}$, $\ce{PF5}$ and many more you can add. In all these there is a controversy of one of these two types:

1. Is formal charge more important than octet rule - as to justify hypervalency- on determining Lewis structure? As a rule I'd say the answer is *no*. For example in $\ce{SO2}$,$\ce{SO3}$, $\ce{SO4^2-}$, Do calculations show it?
2. What is the central atom hybridization? For example, in $\ce{PF5}$ (see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/why-does-f-replace-the-axial-bond-in-pcl5)). Does it involve d-orbitals?

In any case, both previous statements are related to the d-orbitals energy.

There is -at least- one straightforward way to answer the question:

- Calculate* the Molecular Orbitals and see which of previous options fit better (the use of d-orbitals or the non use of them). 
  *sure some can be found in some papers.

So the question is:

**Are there theoretical studies of many concrete examples as to remark that d orbitals don't play any relevant role in covalent bonding?**

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your question? What info are you looking for that is not in the related posts?

Comment: @Greg look at the title, I think the posts below show $d$ orbitals are not important in covalent bonds. I ask what is the Evidence.

Comment: Some related pub.: 1. Gillespie, R. *Coord. Chem. Rev.* **2002,** *233-234*, 53–62. DOI: 10.1016/S0010-8545(02)00102-9 2. Gillespie, R. *Inorg. Chem.* **1995,** *34* (4), 978–979. DOI: 10.1021/ic00108a032 3. Smith, D. *J. Chem. Educ.* **2005,** *82* (8), 1202. DOI: 10.1021/ed082p1202 4. Jensen, W. *J. Chem. Educ.* **2006,** *83* (12), 1751. DOI: 10.1021/ed083p1751 5. Halgren, T. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1977,** *99* (21), 6793–6806. DOI: 10.1021/ja00463a002

Comment: Is this only meant to be about supposedly hypervalent compounds of main group elements?

Comment: Why don't you look for studies that *do* show a significant d orbital contribution to covalent bonding. Proving nonexistence is hard.

Comment: @Karl I have found 2 treating this questions, but couldn't read them completely yet, and both are quite dificult to understand. One from cooper 1994 (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00089a033), the other one from magnusson 1990 (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00178a014).